# Loading Json Objects from text file - Returning Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token " [ "

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ios, json

I'm having a problem with getting my Json Objects from a text file and being able to use them in a javascript function. However it works if there is only one Json Object. Then when I start having multiple Json Objects it gives me the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

Here is my code below:

**iOS**

```
    NSString *post = @"";
    NSDictionary *firstJsonDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1025", @"DateandTime", logString, @"Description", [self getLogTypeName:(LOGS)level], @"LoggingLevel", nil];
    NSMutableArray *arrayTest = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [arrayTest addObject:firstJsonDictionary];
    NSData *jsonData2 = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:arrayTest options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Message=%@", jsonString];

    NSLog(@"Post Data: \n%@", post);
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
    NSURL *logURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"TestPHP.php"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *logRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:logURL];
    [logRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [logRequest setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [logRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [logRequest setHTTPBody:postData];
    NSURLConnection *logConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:logRequest delegate:self];
```

**PHP**

```
    $file = 'testingFile.txt';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    if (isset($_POST['Message'])) {
    // Append a new person to the file
    $current .= $_POST['Message'] . PHP_EOL; 
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);

    } else {
        $Contents = file_get_contents($file);
        echo $Contents;
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
    function GetLoggingData() {
      $.get("../ISOSEC/logging/TestPHP.php", function(data){
          $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(idx, obj) {
             console.log(obj.DateandTime);
             console.log(obj.LoggingLevel);
             console.log(obj.Description);
             AddLog(obj.DateandTime, obj.LoggingLevel, obj.Description);
          });

      });
    }
```

**TextFile**

```
   [
     {
        "DateandTime" : "1025",
        "LoggingLevel" : "ERROR",
        "Description" : "Test"
     }
   ]
   [
     {
       "DateandTime" : "1025",
       "LoggingLevel" : "ERROR",
       "Description" : "Test"
     }
   ]
```

If anyone could explain what i'm doing wrong that would be really great. 
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: @bansi What? [Sure they are.](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-2) Where did you hear that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your string isn't a Valid Json string.
If your modify your string like this, it should work:

```
[
    {
        "DateandTime": "1025",
        "LoggingLevel": "ERROR",
        "Description": "Test"
    },
    {
        "DateandTime": "1025",
        "LoggingLevel": "ERROR",
        "Description": "Test"
    }
]
```

You will also need to adapt your code a bit because the structure you get back is a bit different.

Also, when you want to validate a Json file, you can use [JSonLint.](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: This Json string works, do you know how to fix my code to make the Json string write to file like this? instead of how it's doing it at the moment? As i'm using the NSDictionary in iOS to make the jsonObject.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know IOS, so I cannot help on that part.

Comment: No worries, i'll have alook at how to make a valid json string in iOS. Thanks for helping with showing the valid Json string

Answer (score 1):

This is how you make an array

```
   [
     {
        "DateandTime" : "1025",
        "LoggingLevel" : "ERROR",
        "Description" : "Test"
     },
     {
       "DateandTime" : "1025",
       "LoggingLevel" : "ERROR",
       "Description" : "Test"
     }
   ]
```